# Geodesics in Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Every noncommutative matrix Lie group $G$ can be naturally embedded in some $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$. Moreover, many of them can be realized as algebraic sets. However, the natural images of geodesics of the Lie group (with respect to its canonical affine torsion-free connection), defined by $\gamma(t)=g \cdot e^{tA} (g \in G, A \in \mathfrak{g})$, are in general not algebraic subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$. I only find the Heisenberg group (whose geodesics are quadric curves) as an counterexample (and possibly its Lie subgroups). So is there other counterexample whose geodesics are algebraic? Is it as nilpotent as the Heisenberg group?

**Edit 1**: I suddenly realized that for a generic algebraic set in $\Bbb{R}^n$, there are almost always infinite transcendental geodesics on it.

**Edit 2**: I was wrong about Lie groups. Although Lie groups have geodesics in matrix-exponential form, many of them seem to be pure exponential or trigonometric and so can be realized as algebraic sets in the canonical embeddings in $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: Those translates of one-parameter subgroups are not always geodesics,

Comment: @TedShifrin Then when do they be?

Comment: When the Riemannian metric is bi-invariant!

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited my statement, is it correct now?

Comment: It would seem that you need every matrix to be nilpotent, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Irrational windings on a torus don't seem very algebraic. In some sense, that's "most" one-parameter subgroups of the torus.

Comment: @runway44 I realized this in my 'Edit' part.

Comment: Aren't you effectively asking when the exponential series truncates (i.e., is polynomial) for all $A$ in the Lie algebra...? Maybe I'm confused by the wording.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang A non-truncated exponential series needs not be transcendental.(For example, diagonal matrices with each pair of non-zero element having rational quotient)

Comment: That may be my confusion: Geodesics _tracing an algebraic curve_ versus geodesics _that are algebraic functions of $t$_. It seemed to me (maybe incorrectly) that circles are transcendental from your perspective, though as curves they're algebraic.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I stated in my description that I just require the geodesics to be **algebraic subsets** of $\Bbb{R}^n$.